# HDA intel PCH buzzing sound when playing audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

I've had Linux installed for a while on my HP elite dragonfly G2 and everything going well except the speakers, every time I play a video with audio and have the volume set to a little over 50%... the speakers start making some buzz noise whenever a certain frequency or sound is played. I've tried almost everything I know. please help!! if you need anything for me to link or show please let me know!!!

Comment: What sort of Linux did you install?